# Why my way to update local files with Github is not working?

Tags: github

First I have a master branch in my remote repo on the internet. And I know if I changed my local files, how to update my local changes to the remote repo. Now the problem is, if I don't want my new changes in my local tracked files, how to return back using updating from the remote repo in github?

I have tried the following things:

1. I use

   ```
   git checkout origin master
   ```

   to get to master repo.
2. I make sure that one tracked file, named main_32.f90 is changed a little bit in the comment line.
3. Then I use

   ```
   git pull
   ```
4. it turns out that everything is up to date.

   ```
   Already up-to-date.
   ```
5. I then checked the main_32.f90, it is not the original one but the changed one in comment line. So it means that the *git pull* is not working.

So how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to keep your local changes, you can do a hard reset to a pointer, branch, sha1, etc to discard all changes. `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Use [this kind of aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9074343/1125161) to have a pretty view of your working tree if you are a console fan and don't want to use any GUI as suggested by other users.

Comment: THanks! I just google that there are unofficial GUIs! I only knew that GITHUB for windows and mac.

Comment: @PabPeter ```git status``` is your best friend when using terminal - it tells you what is going on with your working tree. One more advice, use ```git fetch``` before pulling - it will only update the remote refs, but not merge the changes (if any) from the remote repository (google the difference between ```fetch``` and ```pull```).